# Constructing a chain complex to induce an isomorphism on homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

Say we have the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 2$ as a chain complex concentrated at degree zero, i.e.

$\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots$.

How can we, in general, construct a chain complex $B.$ such that there is a map of chain complexes $B. \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ inducing an isomorphism on homology, and $B_i$ is a free abelian group for all $i$?

To be honest, I don't really know how to think about constructing a chain complex to satisfy these conditions. Hints would be appreciated. A complete solution would help me get a better handle of how to approach these kinds of questions in general.

Answer (score 1):

$B_1=B_0=\mathbb Z$ and $d\colon B_1\to B_0$ is multiplication by $n$.